# How to use testthat and travis ci for authorized api calls?

Tags: r, travis-ci, testthat

Im working on a R package which accesses some API.

```
access_api <- function(t,k) {
  if (missing(k)) {
    k <- Sys.getenv("KEY")
    if (identical(k, "")) {
      stop(".Renviron doesnt have that variable", call. = FALSE)
    }
    c <- paste0("www.someapi.com","k",k,"t",t)
  } else {
    c <- paste0("www.someapi.com","k",k",t",t)
   }
return (c)
}
```

In the testthat directory, I have a test which tests that function for some expectations I have towards the structure of the returned data.

```
context("Check data structure")

test_api_call <- access_api(t)


test_that("Check data structure", {

  skip_on_cran() # test should only run on travis

  testthat::expect_true(row.names(test_api_call)[1] == "that")
  testthat::expect_true(row.names(test_api_call)[2] == "this")
  testthat::expect_true(row.names(test_api_call)[3] == "thatthis")

})
```

Locally, everything works fine. On travis however, I get the error message  I have predefined on `access_api()` '.Renviron doesnt have that variable'

Next I followed travis documentation and created some encrypted token corresponding the "KEY" I importing through `Sys.getenv("KEY")`in `access_api()`:

`travis encrypt KEY="somekeyIhave" --add`

The output of that has been added to `.travis.yml`:

```
language: R
sudo: false # required
cache: packages

env:
  matrix:
  - warnings_are_errors: true
  global:
    secure: "OutputOfTraviencrypt"
```

However the error remains. Im missing something here. Unfortunately, the information I found so far on that topic were not pointing to any specific direction.